# Portable projector for rooms with poor lighting

Tags: lighting, light

I have seen some handy man workers have a portable light projector for rooms/areas with poor lighting.
What is the name of such a light as I am interested in buying an affordable one.
Googling for light projectors or similar gives night lights for the bedroom or reading lights

Comment: Maybe try to edit your question and explain and give more information.  Most handymen use work lights for more light, but do not think this is what you want or either holiday light projectors.

Comment: @crip659: instead of a flashlight I have seen a big square lamp placed on the floor that is very luminous. I don't know what's that called

Comment: That is a work light, usually made a bit tougher than a regular floor/desk lamp, and usually able to be much brighter(also use more power).  Usually halogen and can put out a lot of heat.

Comment: The word "projector" is what's throwing you off. Most search results for "projector" will get you something that you plug an HDMI cable in so you can show a movie on the side of the barn. You _could_ use it for lighting up a work area (just display a picture of a snow man on a snowy hill in a blizzard), but they're rather expensive and full of very fragile electronics and not really designed for a work area.

Comment: I use an old bed sheet.  Should I get a barn?

Comment: You might consider a 12v floodlight, like they sell at truck stops. You can power them with a portable power pack or from an AC/DC adapter, making them flexible in different situations. The main advantage is price though; they are cheap and so are the power providers; buying them together offers less flexibility, makes it harder to repair, and enables an "integration premium" (think apple products) factored into the cost. -$0.02

Comment: @dandavis: could you give me an example from amazon?

Comment: if you don't mind the cord, don't bother. I'm mainly advocating against items like dewalt's DCL050, which is $60 and has no battery or charger and isn't even that bright. I would get something like https://www.amazon.com/dp/B008XZAQDU as a light and something like https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00ME3ZH7C/ to power it; mix and match. Landscape and truck lights are the best bang for the buck in terms of bright lights. If handy with electronics, LED replacement headlights can work great for dirt cheap, but does need some creative assembly. You can use #10 solid wire to make it a snake light.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want a "work light".  Don't use "projector" in your search, that will get you lots of other things but not what you want.

Comment: Is the lumens or the Watts what is important to understand how bright it is when choosing one?

Comment: More lumens equal more brightness/light and usually more watts.  Different types of lights, LED,CFL, halogen.  LEDs usually more light for less watts/power.

Comment: @Jim incandescent bulbs were always rated in watts - the more, the brighter. Now that incandescents are an endangered species, bulbs are usually rated in lumens (which is probably a more accurate rating). Again, the more the brighter. I will caution, though, that _too_ bright a light can make it difficult to work. For example, in my crawlspace, too much light on the work area creates very harsh shadows and any area that's in shadow is essentially blackness because my eyes adjust to the brightness of the lit area.

Comment: @FreeMan: Is there a big difference between 50W/4500 lumen and 30W/3000 lumen?

Comment: 4500 lumen is 50% (1500 lm) brighter than 3000 lumen, so I'd say yes.

Comment: @FreeMan: Is the cost also much higher? E.g. would a 100W/9000 lumen be too much? How could I figure out the best option e.g. of the 3 choices? 30W/3000-50W/4500 - 100W/9000. Seems the last with 9000 is the brightest, but I am not sure if the difference is that much if 4500 is already super bright. Also I am not sure if it is more expensive in regards to the electricity bill per hour used.

Comment: Cost is totally off-topic - it varies from day to day and location to location. How bright is too bright is also up to you. It can also depend on the tasks that are to be accomplished. I've got 6 x 5000 lumen overhead fixtures in my garage, but this is broad area lighting. It works well for me but my eyes are getting a little tired. In the dark crawl space, that would be _way_ too much. My suggestion is to buy something cheap and see how you like it. If it works, job done, if not, buy another and/or better one.

Comment: @FreeMan: Thank you for your help and explanation